Shutter curtain not moving as intended? Fixable?
I did buy a Minolta Dynax 600si on a flea market some time ago and now finally wanted to try it. And let me state at this point, that I have no previous experience with film cameras.
At first everything seemed alright and the shutter worked. Then, I inserted a test film (already exposed) into the camera and the wind mechanism seemed also alright. I took some pictures and after the camera displayed 10 or so shots taken, it displayed HELP in the top panel. Then, I opened the back and tried to get the film out (I know not smart if you want to use the pictures you have taken). It was quite hard to remove it and there was some resistance so that I only removed one revolution or so of the film. Then, I googled some stuff and took the battery out, put it back in again, and turned the camera back on (with the back open). The error went away and now removing the rest of the film was actually much easier. Then, everything seemed okay again.
But later at some point (I can't recall what happened immediately before), the shutter curtain has stopped working properly. And when I press the shutter button (in bulb mode), nothing happens with the shutter curtain (the mirror moves up). When I release it, there is some very fast movement of the curtains. When I press the DoF preview button, there is a slight movement of one (or both) of the curtains of about 1/4 of the way up, which also doesn't seem right (But to be honest, I don't know what actually is supposed to happen with the shutter curtains when pressing the DoF preview button. The mirror also seems to move up and down again when releasing the DoF button and the also some shutter curtain stuff moves and the aperture things(?), so I presume that the mirror and curtains might be connected in some kind of way?).
I will try to upload a video of the shutter curtains not moving (see here for video).
I don't know if all the story before the shutter curtain not working mattered but I thought I should better mention everything.
Now, finally of course my question is whether this might be fixable and I'm also happy to hear if you want comment on my general wrongdoings/observations.
Thank you for reading my question!

The shutter leafs do not appear obviously damaged, so I would guess the shutter arm/mechanism has become disconnected/misaligned.
It is probably repairable if you find someone who still works on older film cameras; but it is almost certainly cheaper to buy another one instead.
